# How to shift pandas column elements for given index based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have recently started using python and pandas, please bear with me on this. 
I have two columns (A, B) of data (dataframe) that should be arranged in particular sequence based on certain relation between two columns (let's say elements of column A should be smaller than elements column B for a given index), if relation is not satisfied data should shifted (only for A) by a row starting from the index where condition is not satisfied throughout the length of a column. And it should be replaced by NaN where is condition is not met.

I have tried shift(1) function. This works only if the first element doesn't meet the condition but if there is any other element or multiple elements don't meet criteria it creates multiple NaNs at the start of column A instead of at the place where criteria is not met.

```
mdata1 = [[3,2],[5,4],[8,6],[10,7],[float('NaN'),9],[float('NaN'),11]]
mdf1 = pd.DataFrame(mdata1,columns=['A','B'])

for xt in range (0,len(mdf1)):
    if mdf1.A[xt]>mdf1.B[xt]:
        mdf1['A'] = mdf1['A'].shift(1)
```

Actual result

```
A   B
NaN 2
NaN 4
3.0 6
5.0 7
8.0 9
10.0    11
```

Expected result

```
A   B
NaN 2
3.0 4
5.0 6
NaN 7
8.0 9
10.0    11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you want to do exactly. but by simply altering your code i get the expected results:

```
for xt in range (0,len(mdf1)):
if mdf1.A[xt]>mdf1.B[xt]:
    mdf1.loc[xt:,'A'] = mdf1[xt:]['A'].shift(1)
```

shift(1) shifts the whole column/dataframe by one row, thus you need to start shifting from the index you're at to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was missing, starting a shift (1) operation at required index. This is related to monitoring of an area based on two sensors wherein sensor 1 data is always smaller than sensor 2 but for this to happen both sensors should report data. Sometimes sensor 1 don't and that creates a problem in post analysis . It is lot more complicated than that but this is the easiest explanation I can give.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a `merge_asof` from the original dataframe column B to a dataframe containing only non NaN values from column A. Dropping duplicates in new column will give you the expected result:

```
tmp = pd.merge_asof(mdf1, pd.DataFrame(mdf1.A.dropna().astype(np.int64)),
                    left_on='B', right_on='A', suffixes=('_x', ''))['A']

mdf1['A'] = np.where(tmp.duplicated(), np.nan, tmp)
```